Rook-ceph ceph:v18.2.2 mon pods failing in loop
rook-ceph mons failling rook v1.13
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:42.499+0000 7f43a7779700  1 mon.d@1(peon).paxos(paxos active c 2794..3317) lease_timeout -- calling new election
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:42.500+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : mon.d calling monitor election
2024-07-01T19:25:42.503030854+04:00 debug 2024-07-01T15:25:42.501+0000 7f43a4f74700  1 paxos.1).electionLogic(2904) init, last seen epoch 2904
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:42.549+0000 7f43a4f74700  1 mon.d@1(electing) e7 collect_metadata :  no unique device id for : fallback method has no model nor serial
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:43.777+0000 7f43ab183700  0 log_channel(audit) log [DBG] : from='admin socket' entity='admin socket' cmd='mon_status' args=[]: dispatch
2024-07-01T19:25:43.780274539+04:00 debug 2024-07-01T15:25:43.777+0000 7f43ab183700  0 log_channel(audit) log [DBG] : from='admin socket' entity='admin socket' cmd=mon_status args=[]: finished
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:47.549+0000 7f43a7779700  1 paxos.1).electionLogic(2905) init, last seen epoch 2905, mid-election, bumping
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:47.587+0000 7f43a7779700  1 mon.d@1(electing) e7 collect_metadata :  no unique device id for : fallback method has no model nor serial
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.008+0000 7f43a2f70700  1 mon.d@1(electing) e7 handle_auth_request failed to assign global_id
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.605+0000 7f43a7779700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : mon.d is new leader, mons d,e in quorum (ranks 1,2)
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.660+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 mon.d@1(leader) e7 handle_command mon_command({"prefix": "osd pool create", "format": "json", "pool": ".mgr", "pg_num": 1, "pg_num_min": 1, "pg_num_max": 32, "yes_i_really_mean_it": true} v 0) v1
2024-07-01T19:25:52.661655858+04:00 debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.660+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(audit) log [INF] : from='mgr.999419 ' entity='' cmd=[{"prefix": "osd pool create", "format": "json", "pool": ".mgr", "pg_num": 1, "pg_num_min": 1, "pg_num_max": 32, "yes_i_really_mean_it": true}]: dispatch
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.660+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 mon.d@1(leader) e7 handle_command mon_command([{prefix=config-key set, key=mgr/dashboard/accessdb_v2}] v 0) v1
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.661+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 mon.d@1(leader) e7 handle_command mon_command({"prefix": "osd require-osd-release", "release": "reef", "format": "json"} v 0) v1
2024-07-01T19:25:52.662451609+04:00 debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.661+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(audit) log [INF] : from='client.? ' entity='' cmd=[{"prefix": "osd require-osd-release", "release": "reef", "format": "json"}]: dispatch
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.680+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [DBG] : monmap e7: 3 mons at {c=[v2:10.107.5.229:3300/0,v1:10.107.5.229:6789/0],d=[v2:10.99.48.154:3300/0,v1:10.99.48.154:6789/0],e=[v2:10.101.20.192:3300/0,v1:10.101.20.192:6789/0]} removed_ranks: {0} disallowed_leaders: {}
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.682+0000 7f43a4f74700  1 mon.d@1(leader) e7 collect_metadata :  no unique device id for : fallback method has no model nor serial
2024-07-01T19:25:52.683190867+04:00 debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.682+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [DBG] : fsmap 
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.682+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [DBG] : osdmap e38: 3 total, 3 up, 3 in
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.682+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [DBG] : mgrmap e86: b(active, since 22s), standbys: a
debug 2024-07-01T15:25:52.683+0000 7f43a4f74700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [WRN] : Health check failed: 1/3 mons down, quorum d,e (MON_DOWN)


Issue can be fixed with below solution.
> 1.Contained version should be <1.6 which support all rook-ceph versions
> 2.Update NOFILELimits value in all contained nodes

why infinite value can not be used in NOFILELimits ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212925/on-linux-set-maximum-open-files-to-unlimited-possible/1213069#1213069
what is the solution for more details please have a look
https://github.com/rook/rook/issues/10110
before solution implemented

After solution implemented

now check all mon should be up and running with replicapool and test the PV created automatically using rook-ceph-block storageclass.
